# Schengen visa multiple entry. Is it required to travel from Schengen state to get into Romania?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, romania

I have a multiple entry Schengen visa from Germany. Although I will enter during my return journey, onward journey is directly to Romania. Is it ok ? I am travelling on Sunday (24th Jan 2016)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be okay?

Answer (score 1):

Even though Romania is not part of the Schengen Area, holders of a Schengen visa can enter Romania without a Romanian visa, whether they entered the Schengen area or not, for 90 days within a 180-day window. Entering Romania will not count as entry into the Schengen Area.

Comment: This doesn't address the core of the question, whether it's necessary to enter froma Schengen state.

Comment: The OP's question really isn't that clear. My understanding of it is that he believes Romania is part of the Schengen Area, and is wondering whether it's OK to enter the Schengen Area via Romania, rather than directly to the Schengen visa's originating country. As Romania is not part of the Schengen Area, this is actually not relevant at all. But I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Well the question title seems (to me, at least) pretty unambiguously to support my interpretation.  But the body is indeed confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Being an EU citizen, I have no personal experience with this but the relevant documents (EU regulations, webpages from the Romanian ministry of Foreign Affairs – the later are unfortunately usually quite poorly translated) make no mention of any requirement to enter Romania from the Schengen area to be exempted from the visa requirement, but only to hold specific visas or permits from a Schengen country.

My understanding is that the logic behind the rules is that you must be a trusted traveller/be able to reenter the Schengen area to gain entry in Romania without Romanian visa (that's why a *single entry* Schengen visa is not enough). Your multiple entry visa is ample proof of that, whether you already used it or not so I would not be concerned about entering Romania first.